# Configure Network of Brokers Queue Consumer To Never Be Localhost Unless Broker Failure

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a pair of Brokers configured as a network of brokers with ActiveMQ 5.5.1. Each broker exists on a server that communicates across a WAN.

**BrokerA on ServerA**

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:networkConnectors>
        <amq:networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://BrokerB:61616)" duplex="true" />
    </amq:networkConnectors>
    <amq:transportConnectors>
      <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://BrokerA:61616" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

**BrokerB on ServerB**

```
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:networkConnectors>
        <amq:networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://BrokerA:61616)" duplex="true" />
    </amq:networkConnectors>
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://BrokerB:61616" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

On each server, I have a Java service running that creates the following topic and queue:

```
<amq:queue id="myQueue" physicalName="myQueue" />
<amq:topic id="myTopic" physicalName="MyTopic" />
```

The java service (on each server) creates a producer and a consumer for *myQueue* as well as a producer and consumer for *myTopic*. I want both consumers on *myTopic* to receive all topic messages, which it does. The problem lies with *myQueue*. I only want the configured  broker to consume *myQueue* messages. For example, if BrokerA produces a service message on ServerA, I only want BrokerB on ServerB to consume that message. Right now in my test I am seeing about 50% of messages produced on ServerA consumed by BrokerA and 50% consumed by BrokerB. In addition, if a BrokerB goes offline, BrokerA must accept all *myQueue* messages from both ServerA and ServerB and consume all *myQueue* messages until BrokerB comes back online.

I had thought about using message groups, but I couldn't come up with a good way to detect when failure has occurred to switch which group a message is sent to. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify 'excludedDestinations' to prevent a queue's messages from going to other brokers...

```
<networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://BrokerB:61616)" duplex="true" >
        <excludedDestinations>
            <queue physicalName="myQueue"/>
        </excludedDestinations>
    </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
```

to your other question about making sure the consumer 'never connects to local broker unless broker failure'...if you do the following in your client connection, you'll always connect to a remote broker unless its unavailable...also, you'll recover to the remote broker when it becomes available

```
failover:(tcp://remoteBroker,tcp://localBroker)?randomize=false&priorityBackup=true
```

Comment: Boday, I was trying to exclude _myQueue_ messages from being consumed by the local broker, not the <networkConnector/> configured broker. So if a producer on ServerA sends a message to BrokerA, I *always* want BrokerB to consume the message from the producer on ServerA (unless BrokerB is down). I should have mentioned I'm using ActiveMQ 5.5.1. It appears that _priorityBackup_ is a feature that was added in 5.6.

Comment: lew, you can still use ?randomize=false to make sure you connect to the first broker, etc...otherwise, you can also use queue naming conventions to partition queues or even use authorization to limit access to queues to certain users (http://activemq.apache.org/security.html)...